# Securing a secret key on a linux server to be consumed by a software running on the server

Tags: ubuntu, security, node.js, best-practices, attacks

I'm not an expert in server security and I have a question regarding a situation where server is being compromised. I have a nodejs app which is a bot that only have https connection to read from some api endpoints and also send some data to another endpoint, all these connections are over https. the bot uses a key which is very sensitive and beign constantly used by the software. so my question is:

"**if someone gets access to the server, does it matter how we store the secret key?**"
whether we keep it in hashi vault, aws or environmental variables or even whether we encrypt it with a password which is given to the software when running and not even saved inside the server (which makes it available in app memory), if an attacker gets access to the server, everything is compromised, correct? is there any way that even when someone gained access to our server we could protect our key (which is used constantly in the software)?

i also had this idea to run the software as lambda function on AWS, but if the aws account gets compromised the env is still be shown.

i appreciate any pointers.

p.s: the server is running on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Not really specific to AWS or Linux. Using multiple keys across hosts can mitigate this somewhat.

A lot of people have surprises waiting for them if they have some key or credentials such as for vendors/APIs, and one day someone fat fingers a credential, then an account is locked, or it is compromised and locked due to unusual activity, and everything using the credential fails until all works using it are paused, credential is reset, and all places using it are reconfigured and restarted. You typically discover other places where it is used when this occurs.

To answer your question, it needs to be something your auditor is ok with. I've seen things like a certificate in each host that you can grant permission to a specific account to read/use, and use powershell/python to read the certificate and private key, and use that to access Vault. Cloud providers also have their own HSM if you want to do it properly. https://aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/

I'm not a fan with using variables for this, but it seems to be more common than I thought.

Part of the decision is what process do you want to perform when you need to reset credentials/API key. Changing the environment variables or a certificate.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49725/is-it-really-secure-to-store-api-keys-in-environment-variables

Comment: thanks for the response, the nodejs app is pretty simple, doesnt serve anything on any port, more like a service running indefinitely, just want to make sure even if someone could get access to the server, the secret key inside, would be safe.
but seem this is not possible, can make it a little bit time consuming to get exposed using different techniques, but someone who got access to the server, with lots of security measures, wouldnt be much bothered to pass those safty measures in place for the secret key.